# Discrepancy between the rate of heat flow

Tags: thermal-conductivity

I'm in a introductory college physics class, and my professor recently gave us this formula for the rate of heat flow:

$\frac{dQ}{dt} = \frac{A \Delta T}{R_{factor}}$ where $R_{factor}$ is $\frac{L}{K}$ with $L$ as the length of the material and $K$ as the thermal conductivity.

He also gave us this formula for the $R_{factor}$ for materials in parallel:

$R_{factor, total} = (\frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + ... + \frac{1}{r_n})^{-1}$ for $n$ materials in parallel.

In class, I proposed this situation and he said that it was "circular reasoning":

[image]

Let's say the thermal conductivity of the cream material is equal to the thermal conductivity of the green material.

Let's say the area of each wall individually is $1\ m^2$. Let's say also that the difference in temperatures that the walls separate is $1\ K$.

Using the formula, for Wall A $$\frac{dQ_1}{dt} = \frac{1}{R_{factor, cream}}.$$

Similarily, for Wall B $$\frac{dQ_2}{dt} = \frac{1}{\frac{1}{R_{factor, cream}} + \frac{1}{R_{factor, cream}}}.$$

The walls are identical in terms of thermal conductivity, so $$\frac{dQ_1}{dt} = \frac{dQ_2}{dt}.$$

However, that would mean that the $R_{factor}$ is either infinite or zero, which creates more mathematical problems, but it clearly cannot be.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Several things...  (1) Areas have units of length squared; (2) $$R_{1}^{-1} + R_{2}^{-1} \neq \left( R_{1} + R_{2} \right)^{-1}$$; (3) ignoring the issue I pointed out in (2), your expression for $dQ_{2}/dt$ would be 1/2 $dQ_{1}/dt$, not equal to it...

Comment: I agree with 1 and 2, those were mistakes, but they still don't take validity away from my argument. Why would the rates not be equal? They're essentially the same wall. Same area, same length/thickness, and the same overall thermal conductivity.

Comment: Because $$\left( R_{1}^{-1} + R_{2}^{-1} \right) = \frac{ R_{1} + R_{2} }{ R_{1} \ R_{2} } $$ which in your example would reduce to $2/R_{factor,cream} \neq 1/R_{factor,cream}$

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. Are you saying that the rate of heat flow through two walls with equal area, equal, uniform thermal conductivity are different?

Comment: I am just stating the mathematical result of your approximations.  Your intuition is on the right track but this would bring your assumption of $$R_{tot} = \left(\sum_{i} R_{i}^{-1}\right)^{-1}$$ into doubt if your intuition were correct, would it not?  So then the question is, why would stacking two objects of material A next to each other have a lower R-value than one object of the same total volume-area relationships of the same material?

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. I guess my professor had given me the wrong equation.

Comment: No, most likely not... It's just a good idea to be careful with approximations.  You did the right thing by taking the limit as the two materials became the same though.  That is exactly what you should do in physics!

Answer (score 1):

You start with the equation
$$ \dot Q = \frac{A \Delta T}{R} \,. $$
I write $\dot Q$ for $\mathrm d Q / \mathrm dt$, it is a common short notation.
Since there is only one $R$ here, I do not need the subscript “factor”. Then
the $R$ is given by $L/K$ where $L$ is the length of the material. The $K$ is a
material constant.

In your example you have one cream wall with material constant $K$. The length
(or rather thickness) of the segment is $L = 1 \, \mathrm m$. From this we can
compute $R$. Taking $A = 1 \, \mathrm m^2$, we obtain a certain $\dot Q$.

Now to the wall “B” example. Here you split the wall into pieces. As we assume
the same $K$ for the green segment, nothing should change. The quantity $R$ is
not changed: $L$ is the same as before, $K$ is the same as before.

The thing that did change is the surface area. So now we have the following:
$$ \dot Q = \frac{(A/2) \Delta T}{R} + \frac{(A/2) \Delta T}{R} \,. $$
The total heat loss is given by two parts, the heat loss through the green
segment and through the cream segment. As those wall are “in parallel” and not
“serial”, we have to add the two heat loss rates together. Each of the segments
has only half the surface area now. Therefore the expression above has $A/2$ in
it. Taking the sum of both summands will give the original result -- nothing
has changed.

In the comments you said that I made the factors up as I go along. This is what
I meant that you get a factor two that will drop out later on.

---

Although you did not ask for it, let me also show you the other case. The wall
is split the other way. Now the heat first has to go through the green piece
and then also through the cream piece. In this case, $K$ has not changed
either. But we have halved $L$, the thickness of the material to be $L/2$. The
surface area is the same now. The factor $R$ has now changed for the materials,
it is $(L/2)/K = L/(2K)$ now. As the materials are “serial” now, we need to do
this inverse addition to add them up. Using this, we will have
$$ R_\text{total} = \left( \frac{2K}{L} + \frac{2K}{L} \right)^{-1} \,. $$
This can be simplified. Both fractions are just the same, we can add them up to
give $L/K$ in the parentheses. We then have
$$ R_\text{total} = \left( \frac{4K}{L} \right)^{-1} \,, $$
which can be simplified to
$$ R_\text{total} = \frac{L}{4K} \,. $$
So although we have just done a thought experiment by splitting the wall in
two layers, the result has changed. This is wrong and suggests that one of the
equations is not correct.

Comment: The thickness is the same, the cross sectional area is different.

Comment: Well, then you forgot the factor $1/2$ in the $A$. There will be two summands, one containing the cream $R$, the other the blue one. Since they are equal, you can add both fractions and get the result of the single wall back.

Comment: It seems like you are just modifying factors as is necessary. Are the equations I'm using wrong?

Answer (score 1):

You have made an error in assuming that R(*factor,cream*) will be the same in both cases.

- $R=L/(K.A)$
- Here $K$ and $A$ are constant but $L$ in first case is twice of that in the second case. Thus if we assume the thermal resistance of the cream coloured layer to be $R$ in the first case, then in becomes $R/2$ in the second case. And as the dimensions of the green layer is same as that of the cream layer, it has the same thermal resistance of $R/2$
- The condition now is          $1/(R) = 1/(0.5R+0.5R)$  , which is true.
  Hope that I have cleared your doubt.

Comment: So you're saying that my professor incorrectly factored the area outside of the formula for the $R_{factor}$?

Comment: From Fourier's Law for heat conduction, R=L/(K.A)...........that's all what i'm  saying

Comment: So the equation for the total $R_{factor}$ can only be used when the area is used to scaled the $R_{factor}$'s?

Comment: Yes. Also , dQ_{1}/dt = dQ_{2}/dt